# При нажатии button, берется значение из textbox и обрабатывается switch c#

Tags: c#, button, textbox

///Прошу сильно не пинать, первый вопрос тут, только 2 дня назад начал изучать СИ Шарп.

Есть Textbox, button1

Нужно:

1. При нажатии button1 введеные значения в Textbox положить в переменную.
2. Через switch сделать проверку.

Введенными данными является строка с буквами и цифрами.

Накидал примерный код, но дальше сообразить не могу:

```
switch (stroka)
{
case "строка":
case "строка2":
case "строка3":
какая-нибудь команда;
break;
default:
какая-нибудь команда;
break;
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: С учётом того, что вы не пишете, что за проверки, что за команда и что конкретно непонятно -- в вашем вопросе отсутствует собственно вопрос. Не на что отвечать.

Comment: "Если бы я хоть разок прочел про глаз!" http://smartfiction.ru/prose/waiting_interest/ может почитать про C#? - не придется задавать такие вопросы

Comment: ...кроме того, не понятно какой фреймворк: WPF или же WinForms?

Comment: Например, юзер вводит значение "fdNgsdasd" в поле texbox и нажимает кнопку button1
Далее  "fdNgsdasd"  сравниванивается с помощью switch. При положительном результате срабатывается комманда Messagebox

Речь идет об WindowsForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кликаем на ваш `Button` на форме 2 раза, и у вас создаётся событие `onClick`
Далее пишем туда код

```
string stroka;
stroka = textBox1.Text; // Кладём вашу строку из TextBox в переменную
switch(stroka) {
    case "строка" : //ваш код
    break; // оператор break необходим после каждого case
}
```

хотя ещё проще можно сделать так:

```
 switch(textBox1.Text) {
        case "строка" : //ваш код
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно. Все заработало. Только плюсик пока поставить не могу почему-то.

Comment: @LEX Потому что не хватает репутации. Просто поставьте галку слева от ответа.